# Is there a difference in how AdoptOpenJDK and AzulOpenJDK handle new File("version")?

Tags: java, gradle, build.gradle, adoptopenjdk, azul-zulu

I have the below in my build.gradle file

```
static def getVersionName() {
    return new File("version").getText().trim()
}
```

When I use AdoptOpenJDK, it compiles well. However, when I use AzulOpenJDK, it complains:

```
* What went wrong:
A problem occurred evaluating project ':app'.
> version (No such file or directory)
```

Is there a difference in how AdoptOpenJDK and AzulOpenJDK handle the above command?

Comment: I'm almost 100% sure that there's no difference in how they handle this code. The problem has to be in something else about the environment: What the current directory is or *maybe* something like how they treat setting "unsettable" system properties like `user.dir`. Can you provide a minimal, reproducible example? If that code itself was behaving different, then a trivial Java class should be able to demonstrate that.

Comment: Don't rely on the working directory in a Gradle script, use e.g. `rootDir` for the root project directory.

Comment: @Joachim Sauer, I'm using the same machine, just switch over the different JDK. So the environment is exactly the same

Comment: Thanks, @Clashsoft. Unfortunately `rootProject.rootDir` only available in non static function. Any advice?

Comment: Make it not static, or pass the project as a parameter.

Comment: Nice one. That works!

Answer (score 2):

Making it

```
def getVersionName() {
    return new File(rootProject.rootDir, "version").getText().trim()
}
```

now works for both. Thanks @Clashsoft